# Struct node next pointer

Tags: c, pointers, free

I have a struct which holds a `next` pointer to a struct of the same type.

I have the following code which stores the number of the struct that the `node` pointer stores, frees it, and sets node to the `node->next`. How is `node->next` known what it is if `free` has been called right before it?

```
double data = node->element;
free(node)
node = node->next;
return data;
```

However, following the same logic, the following code segfaults. The only difference is that this uses a `node` and the other just stores the element in its basic data type.

```
struct node *temp;
temp = node;
free(node);
node = node->next;
return temp;
```

Why is this happening? And how does the first segment of code work anyway?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't *ever* dereference a freed pointer - it is asking for trouble and is likely the source of your segfault. Even if it doesn't segfault, you cannot make any assumptions on the vailidity of the data at that memory address and so it is just not a good thing to do. 
You haven't given too many details in your question but why not modify your code slightly to try this order instead

```
struct node *temp = node->next;
free(node);
return temp;
```

this way you store the pointer before deleting `node` and should not get a segfault

As for the first code

```
double data = node->element;
free(node)
node = node->next;
return data;
```

why not just replace with

```
double data = node->element;
free(node)
return data;
```

as this removes the code that accesses freed memory, and your line

```
node = node->next;
```

is practically pointless when in the next line you free `node` anyway.

Comment: Yes this makes sense - but why does the first piece of code work? Consider struct to hold `double data` and `struct node *next`.

Comment: @Darksky: the first version doesn't work. It _appears_ to work. It's undefined behavior. It could stop working any time for any reason.

Comment: @Darksky Once you free the memory, you MAY be able to access it still and you may not. I think it will depend on where the memory is. The point is that you should not *attempt* it as any data at that address is likely meaningless - you just cannot rely on it. Accessing freed memory is just not a good idea. See the comment of Mat above

Comment: @mathematician1975 shouldn't `struct node *temp = node->next` not work once you free `node`? I think I will need to copy the struct so temp should not be a pointer. Am I right?

Comment: I ended up returning the pointer without freeing it and requiring the other class to free it. So returning an allocated node.

Comment: @Darksky You are setting `temp` to point to the object `node->next`. That node will be a separate object to the node that you free (as you haven't given the code for struct node I cannot say for sure)